# Turn an array of Active Record objects into a hash

Tags: ruby

I have an array of Active Record objects. I'd like to create a hash that serves as an index. My Active Record objects have the properties `name` and `value`.

Ideally I'd like to iterate over the array and create a hash that will create something similar to:

```
hash[name] = value
```

What's the best way to create an array `foo` to create a hash similar to the one above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
hash = {}
Model.all.map { |i| hash[i.id] = i }
```

`hash` should then evaluate to:

```
{
  :1 => #<ActiveRecord:1>,
  :2 => #<ActiveRecord:2>,
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`Hash::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D).

```
relation = Record.where("query")

Hash[
  relation.to_a.map do |obj|
    [obj.name, obj.value]
  end
]
```